# Can I use a Desktop as a docker server and connect via a mac to the hosted adderess?

Tags: docker, server

Can I use a Desktop as a docker server and connect via a mac to the hosted address? I have some applications I am running on my mac and they are killing the processing speed so I was wondering if I could offload them to a PC hosted server?

Comment: The _remote_ Docker server will be a MacOS like the client or another OS?

Comment: Another OS Microsoft PC